# Retrieving Values in a Dictionary in C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

So I have a code that has a Dictionary that looks like the following

```
Dictionary<int, List<object>> records = new Dictionary<int, List<object>>();
```

Now the dictionary is populated bot the list of objects and int.

My question is the list of Objects.

I need to retrieve those values how do I do it?

Please note that everything is populated I just need to retrieve the values from the list of objects and convert it to an array.

Comment: Do you want to convert all the Lists in the dictionary into a single array, or convert each list into its own corresponding array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this

```
foreach (var item in records)
{
    // records will have key & value
    var arr = item.Value.ToArray();
}



      foreach (var item in records)
        {
            // records will have key & value
            var key = item.key;
            var arr = item[key].ToArray();
        }
```

Comment: The `var` will be a `KeyValuePair`, so you can get the `Key` and `Value` properties from there. `Value` will be the `List<object>`.

Comment: @gunr2171 - If you're referring to my now deleted comment, yes.  I missed the `.Value` in the code before it was formatted.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<object> list = records[0];
```

Just reference by int key. A dictionary is a key value data structure, so if you need sequential access to your records I would consider an array/list instead. 
However, it is possible to loop through the dictionary as already described by @praga2050.

Comment: You might want to change `var` to `List<object>`, just to make things clearer.

Comment: Is there a way to get the values without referencing the key?

Comment: @user768241, a dictionary is only designed to get values like this. How else were you thinking of doing it?